# Operator 'Like' is not defined for types '1-dimensional array of String' and 'String'

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run a simple script:

```
returnvalue = 0

If   {Term Description} like "Summer*" Then 
returnvalue = 1 
end if
```

and I get the error "Operator 'Like' is not defined for types '1-dimensional array of String' and 'String'."

I don't know a lot of VB but I suppose that I'm using the wrong command for the data type I'm trying to compare, so what are my alternatives?

Comment: You're trying to compare with the wrong thing.  You don't want to compare with the array as a whole, you want to compare with elements of it.  The suggestion below is a better choice for what you're specifically trying to do with the `Like` operator, but a more general alternative would be something like `If arrayVar.Any(Function(s) s Like "Summer*") Then returnValue = 1`.

Comment: Thanks but now I get the 'Any' is not a member of 'System.Array'. error

Comment: Requires `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the file.  It's an extension method from Linq.  I'm not sure if you would need `s As String` in the lambda declaration, I don't remember if arrays implement `IEnumerable(Of T)` or just `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Also: if you prefer the more general approach, I can write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are trying to do is check if any of the elements in the array starts with the string "Summer". You can use a for loop. Like this:

```
Dim arr() As String = {Term, Description}
For Each s As String in arr
    If (s.StartsWith("Summer")) Then
        returnval = 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks but now 2 errors shown -Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'. and 's' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.